Why added ckeditor in Laravel 11 app lose itself when I start type inside of ckeditor area?
Reading
https://startutorial.com/view/using-ckeditor-with-laravel-livewire
article I added ckeditor in Laravel 11 app in 1 page just as on example and it works ok.
But to have the editor some default text I remade it as :
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-10">
        <div wire:ignore>
            <textarea wire:model="message"
                      class="min-h-fit h-48 "
                      name="message"
                      id="message">{{ $message }}</textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span class="text-lg">You typed:</span>
            <div class="w-full min-h-fit h-48 border border-gray-200">{{ $message }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

To put $message inside of textarea block was a decision for me - maybe not best.
So I have an editor with ckeditor and default text, but when I start enter text inside of ckeditor area - ckeditor itself is lost
and I see plain textarea and in "You typed" block I see newly text.
I have a component editor:
namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Enums\AppColorEnum;
use App\Enums\ConfigValueEnum;
use App\Enums\DispatchAlertTypeEnum;
use App\Library\ImageProps;
use App\Library\Traits\AppCommonTrait;
use App\Livewire\Forms\NewsCategoryForm;
use App\Models\NewsCategory;
use App\Rules\NewsCategoryRules;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use NewsCategoryActiveEnum;

class NewsCategoryEditor extends Component
{
    use AppCommonTrait;
    use WithFileUploads;
    public string $pageTitle = 'News category editor';
    public ?int $id = null;
    public bool $isEdit = false;
    public NewsCategoryForm $form;
    public array $imageProps = [];
    public array $activeSelectionItems = [];
    public array $appColorSelectionItems = [];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.news-category-editor')->layout('components.layouts.admin');
    }

    public function mount(?int $id = null, ?string $defaultAction = null)
    {
        ...
        if(!blank($id)) {
            $this->edit($id);
        }
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $this->isEdit = true;
        try {
            $newsCategory = NewsCategory::getById($id)->firstOrFail();
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            self::dispatchAlert(DispatchAlertTypeEnum::ERROR,'Error reading news category: ' . $e->getMessage(), $this->pageTitle);
        }
        $this->form->setNewsCategory($newsCategory, $this->isEdit);
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        ...
    } // public function update()



    public function cancel()
    {
        $this->redirect(route('admin.newsCategories.index'), navigate: true);
    }

}

I use form app/Livewire/Forms/NewsCategoryForm.php :
namespace App\Livewire\Forms;

use App\Models\NewsCategory;
use Livewire\Form;

class NewsCategoryForm extends Form
{
    public NewsCategory $newsCategory;
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $description;
    ...
    public bool $isEdit = false;

    public function setNewsCategory(NewsCategory $newsCategory, bool $isEdit)
    {
        $this->newsCategory = $newsCategory;
        $this->name = $newsCategory->name;
        $this->description = $newsCategory->description;
        ...
        $this->isEdit = $isEdit;
    }

    public function getNewsCategory(): NewsCategory
    {
        $this->newsCategory->name = $this->name;
        $this->newsCategory->description = $this->description;
        ...
        return $this->newsCategory;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }


}

and blade template :
<div class="editor_form_wrapper">

    <form class="form-editor" @if($form->isEdit)  wire:submit="update"
          @else  wire:submit="store" @endif enctype="multipart/form-data">

        @include('admin.validation_errors', ['show_error_items' => true])

        @if($form->isEdit)
            <div class="editor_field_block_wrapper">
                <div class="editor_field_block_device_splitter">
                    <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3">
                        <label for="id" class="editor_field_block_device_label">Id: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="editor_form_readonly" value="{{ $form->id }}"
                               tabindex="-1" readonly/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif


        <div class="editor_field_block_wrapper">
            <div class="editor_field_block_device_splitter">
                <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3 ">
                    <label for="name" class="editor_field_block_device_label">Name: <span
                            class="editor_form_aria_required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 w-full">
                    <input id="name" type="text"
                           class="editor_form_input"
                           maxlength="50"
                           wire:model="form.name"
                           autocomplete="off"
                           placeholder="Fill string describing news category"
                           tabindex="10"
                           autofocus/>
                    @error('form.name')
                    <span class="error_text">{{$message}}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="editor_field_block_wrapper">
            <div class="editor_field_block_device_splitter">
                <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3">
                    <label for="description" class="editor_field_block_device_label">Description: <span
                            class="editor_form_aria_required" aria-required="true"> * </span> </label>
                </div>
                <div class="px-2 w-full">
                    <textarea wire:model="form.description"
                              class="min-h-fit h-48 " rows="4" cols="80"
                              name="description"
                              id="description">{{ $form->description }}</textarea>
                    <div>
                        <span class="text-lg">You typed:</span>
                        <div class="w-full min-h-fit h-48 border border-gray-200">{{ $form->description }}</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                @error('form.description')
                <span class="error_text">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>


        ...
          
        @if($form->isEdit)
            <div class="editor_field_block_wrapper">
                <div class="editor_field_block_device_splitter">
                    <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3 ">
                        <label for="created_at" class="editor_field_block_device_label">Created at</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <input
                            id="created_at" name="created_at" type="text"
                            class="editor_form_readonly"
                            value="{{ $form->created_at }}"
                            tabindex="-1"
                            readonly/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            @if(!blank($form->updated_at))
                <div class="editor_field_block_wrapper">
                    <div class="editor_field_block_device_splitter">
                        <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3 ">
                            <label for="updated_at" class="editor_field_block_device_label">Updated at</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 w-full">
                            <input
                                id="updated_at" name="updated_at" type="text"
                                class="editor_form_readonly"
                                value="{{ $form->updated_at }}"
                                tabindex="-1"
                                readonly/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endif

        <div class="flex items-center justify-end p-2 text-right sm:px-6">
            <div class="mb-3 flex justify-between">
                <button class="btn_editor_form_cancel" wire:click="cancel">
                    Cancel
                </button>

                <button class="btn_editor_form_submit" type="submit">
                    Edit 
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>





    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#description'))
            .then(editor => {
                editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                    console.log('editor.getData()::')
                    console.log(editor.getData())

                @this.set('form.description', editor.getData());
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>

Any ideas what is wrong in my code and how to fix it ?

It seems that in the view you forgot to enclose the <textarea> with a wire:ignore as you showed in the initial code snippet, so when Livewire updates the DOM also rewrites the textarea and ClassicEditor loses its references.
BUT in this particular view, for a reason I haven't been able to figure out yet, there is an element that causes problems.
It is:
input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="editor_form_readonly" value="{{ $form-> id }}" tabindex="-1" readonly />

Trying to rename id and name (e.g. id="_id" name="_id") everything seems to work fine. Keep in mind however that not having a wire:model the input would also be ignored by Livewire. The only thing I can think of is that Livewire has a mechanism that prevents the id column of a model from being changed but I'm not sure if that's relevant to this case...

A suggestion: since @this.set() makes an ajax call everytime you type a character, I recommend changing it like this:
editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {

   @this.form.description = editor.getData(); // <~~~ THIS
})

in this way the changes are kept locally and they can be sent to the backend when the form is submitted.
If you want, for debugging purposes, a button that performs the update can be added to the view:
<button type="button" wire:click="$refresh">
    Refresh
</button>

Also, since you printed the initial value of the textarea in the HTML, you could remove wire:model="form.description" from it, because this property is handled by @this.form.description = editor.getData()

Thanks a lot! Yes I had to rename input id="id"  looks like "id" - is reserved word
